# How do I flip a range in SSE while keeping one value unchanged?

Tags: assembly, x86, vectorization, x86-64, sse

I have a vector of eight unsigned 8 bit numbers in the range 0 .. 12 in `xmm0`. I want to perform the following translation on each element `e` in the vector:

```
if (e != 12)
    e = 11 - e;
```

That is, the number 0, 1, ..., 11 are changed to 11, 10, ..., 0 whereas 12 is left unchanged. Other values do not occur, I don't care what happens to them.

How can I implement this operation efficiently with the SSE4 instruction set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SSE2 (you didn't ask, but..), I propose the following, reusing the mask from the comparison to do funny negation:

```
e = (e ^ mask) + (12 & mask)
```

Which for a true mask turns into `~e + 12 = -e + -1 + 12 = 11 - e` and for a false mask it's obviously the identity.

Or in vector stuff, (not tested)

```
movdqa xmm1, [vec12]
pcmpgtb xmm1, xmm0
pxor xmm0, xmm1
pand xmm1, [vec12]
paddb xmm0, xmm1
```

For SSSE3 and up, you could use our old friend `pshufb`, since with this range of values it can be 16-entry table lookup: (not tested)

```
movdqa xmm1, [table]
pshufb xmm1, xmm0
```

Where the table looks like (not tested)

```
.db 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 12, "yolo"
```

Comment: Oh wow, I totally forgot about pshufb! For the first one, I thought of doing (((12 - v) + 243) - 243) where the addition is a saturating addition, which would move the result in the right places. But with all the mask loads for that, your approach is likely faster.